# Replacing 'media_keys' with 'preview_url' in Twitter API JSON return file?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am doing an application in Node.js using the Twitter API. The way the Twitter API is setup you get a JSON file such as:

```
result = {
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1410481286947483648",
        "created_at": "2021-07-01T06:11:58.000Z",
        "text": "RT @weatherdak: Absolutely mind-blowing wildfire behavior in British Columbia.\n\nIncredible &amp; massive storm-producing pyrocumulonimbus plume…"
    },
    {
        "attachments": {
            "media_keys": [
                "7_1408149248726667266"
            ]
        },
        "id": "1408168068237434883",
        "created_at": "2021-06-24T21:00:04.000Z",
        "text": "RT @Brophyst: Tornado in Brno, Czech Republic :O "
    },

    {
        "attachments": {
            "media_keys": [
                "16_1406870837026770949"
            ]
        },
        "id": "1406870843972632579",
        "created_at": "2021-06-21T07:05:22.000Z",
        "text": "Working on a new storm chasing application with incoming thunder rumbling. "
    },
    {
        "id": "1405081317985947648",
        "created_at": "2021-06-16T08:34:26.000Z",
        "text": "@thefunkygirl @TornadoGreg @cgphotography Slender tornadoes are (almost) the best!"
    }
],
"includes": {
    "media": [
        {
            "media_key": "7_1408149248726667266",
            "preview_image_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/1408149248726667266/pu/img/qNKbx0MtaSGG0Sv0.jpg",
            "type": "video"
        },
        {
            "media_key": "16_1406870837026770949",
            "preview_image_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/E4Y1koXWUAU1Ls5.jpg",
            "type": "animated_gif"
        }
    ]
},
"meta": {
    "oldest_id": "1405081317985947648",
    "newest_id": "1410481286947483648",
    "result_count": 10,
    "next_token": "7140dibdnow9c7btw3z0ry2hiovfdas2sur0h2hu1m6ns"
}
```

}

How do I create a new JSON where instead of getting the attachments/media_keys subsection and the additional 'includes' subsection in the JSON, I can replace the attachment/media_keys with the preview_url?

For example, so that:

```
{
    "attachments": {
        "media_keys": [
            "16_1406870837026770949"
        ]
    },
    "id": "1406870843972632579",
    "created_at": "2021-06-21T07:05:22.000Z",
    "text": "Working on a new storm chasing application with incoming thunder rumbling."
},
```

becomes:

```
{
    "preview_image_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/E4Y1koXWUAU1Ls5.jpg",
       
    "type": "animated_gif"         
    "id": "1406870843972632579",
    "created_at": "2021-06-21T07:05:22.000Z",
    "text": "Working on a new storm chasing application with incoming thunder rumbling."
},
```